# Stored Procedure containing Multiple If Else Select Statements

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures, exists

First Time Poster! :D

I have been searching for an answer to this everywhere, and as simple as I would think it should be, I can't find a straight answer anywhere. I am trying to create a stored procedure that will store multiple, potentially hundreds of select statements... Only one of which will actually end up running... after the `@Look` parameter is given (i.e. the table name).

However, I keep getting this error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

The error is pointing to the `Else If` and `Else` statements. How do I introduce `exists` to these statements? I've tried adjusting them to no avail.

Here is my script from a sample database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Look]  
     (@Look varchar(50)) 
AS
    DECLARE @Lookup VARCHAR(500)

    IF (@Look = 'Employee_Information') 
       SET @Lookup = (SELECT EmployeeId, EmployeeSSN, EmployeeStatus  
                      FROM Employee_Information)
    Else If (@Look = 'Employee_Demographic') 
       SET @Lookup = (SELECT LastName, FirstName, DateOfBirth
                      FROM Employee_Demographic)
    Else 
       SET @Lookup = 'No Table'

    SELECT @Lookup
```

Comment: what made you think to have logic in SP whereas it can be easily handled into you Business Layer

Comment: [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: I'm honestly fairly new to SQL and this is a small project I'm working on, so I'm not entirely sure what you are referring to with regards to it being handled by the Business Layer?

Comment: It looks like you want to have the `Select` statement as Dynamic SQL.

Comment: what do you plan to do with `@Lookup` ?

Comment: Why not just write the separate procedures for each table and call them specifically when needed?

Comment: The intent is to set the @Lookup to the select statement that is chosen based on the parameter provided, in hopes that it would run the select statement as a result.

Comment: This sounds like a **horribly awful design** - you need to read up on the **single responsibility principle** - any piece of code should have **exactly one** responsibility - one procedure, one task - do **not** put gazillion of different selects into a single stored procedure  - this will cause nothing but grief!

Comment: This procedure would have only one responsibility, to run a specific select statement based on the variable given. M. Ali has provided a great alternative below, but I'm waiting to see how he would get around the issue of each select statement having specific columns that would need to be pulled. This is essentially a fast way to pull table views to allow someone to assess the data quickly without having to type each one out.

Comment: I think you'll be waiting a long time. Take what he has built for you and add your logic for what columns to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can make the assumption that the value of @Look variable will be the table name, then all you really need to do is set a variable to contain the columns names.  The stored procedure could look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Look]  
(@Look varchar(50)) 

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- check for sql injection
IF CHARINDEX(';', ISNULL(@Look,'')) != 0
BEGIN
 RAISERROR('Invalid input parameter', 16, 1)
 RETURN -1
END

Declare @SQL nvarchar(MAX);    

IF (@Look = 'Employee_Information') 
    SET @SQL = N'EmployeeId, EmployeeSSN, EmployeeStatus'                    
ELSE IF (@Look = 'Employee_Demographic') 
    SET @SQL = N'LastName, FirstName, DateOfBirth'

IF (@SQL is not null)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + @SQL + ' FROM '+  QUOTENAME(@Look) + ';';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
END
ELSE
    SELECT 'No Table'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is wonderful and accomplishes what I was looking to do. I was way off the mark from my original design and I appreciate you taking the time to put this together. :) I can't say I entirely understand everything that is going on in this answer, but it works and it's wonderful, so that's good enough for me. I'll need to dig into and figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why you are doing this but if you have to for some strange reason, do it something like this.....

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[usp_Look]    --<-- do not use sp_ prefix for user procs
 @Look SYSNAME                       --<-- Use appropriate data type for sql server objects
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  Declare @Sql nvarchar(MAX);

        -- Use dynamic sql rather than using if..else blocks
IF OBJECT_ID(@Look) IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
    SET @Sql = N' SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Look) + ';';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql;
 END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'Table Does not exists';
  END 

END
```

Comment: This would be a good resolution if I were to keep the selected columns the same for every table; however, in this case each select statement needs to pull a different specific set of columns. I like this script you've provided a lot, but would need to get over that hump. Also, the intent is to declare each table name with a short cut, i.e. instead of Employee_Information, it would be EI and that is the parameter you would provide with @Look.